# dynamically growing array in numba jitted functions

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-arrays, numba

It seems that `numpy.resize` is not supported in numba.

What is the best way to use dynamically growing arrays with `numba.jit` in nopython mode?

So far the best I could do is define and resize the arrays outside the jitted function, is there a better (and neater) option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy.resize` is a [pure python function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1078-L1140):

```
import numpy as np

def resize(a, new_shape):
    """I did some minor changes so it all works with just `import numpy as np`."""
    if isinstance(new_shape, (int, np.core.numerictypes.integer)):
        new_shape = (new_shape,)
    a = np.ravel(a)
    Na = len(a)
    if not Na:
        return np.zeros(new_shape, a.dtype)
    total_size = np.multiply.reduce(new_shape)
    n_copies = int(total_size / Na)
    extra = total_size % Na

    if total_size == 0:
        return a[:0]

    if extra != 0:
        n_copies = n_copies+1
        extra = Na-extra

    a = np.concatenate((a,)*n_copies)
    if extra > 0:
        a = a[:-extra]

    return np.reshape(a, new_shape)
```

For 1D arrays this would be straight-forward to implement yourself. Unfortunatly it's a lot more complicated for ND arrays because some operations aren't supported in nopython numba functions: `isinstance`, `reshape` and the tuple-multiplication. Here is the 1D equivalent:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def resize(a, new_size):
    new = np.zeros(new_size, a.dtype)
    idx = 0
    while True:
        newidx = idx + a.size
        if newidx > new_size:
            new[idx:] = a[:new_size-newidx]
            break
        new[idx:newidx] = a
        idx = newidx
    return new
```

when you don't want that "repeat input" behaviour and only use it for *increasing the size* it's even easier:

```
@nb.njit
def resize(a, new_size):
    new = np.zeros(new_size, a.dtype)
    new[:a.size] = a
    return new
```

These functions are decorated with `numba.njit` and can therefore be called in any numba functions in nopython mode.

---

A word of caution though: Generally you don't want to resize - or if you do then make sure you choose an approach that has [amoritzed `O(1)` cost (Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). If you can estimate the maximum length then it's better to pre-allocate a correctly sized (or slightly overallocated) array immediatly.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Too bad there's no simple solution for ND arrays.

Comment: you can use np.empty(new_size, a.dtype) instead for very small and debatable performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the strategy I employ is to just allocate more than enough array storage to accommodate the calculation and then keep track of the final index/indices used, and then slice the array down to the actual size before returning. This assumes that you know beforehand what the maximum size you could possibly grow the array to is. The thought is that in most of my own applications, memory is cheap but resizing and switching between python and jitted functions a lot is expensive.

Comment: Thanks, I resize my array by a factor of 2 each time it's full, so I end up with log(max_size) switches between python and jitted functions. Do you reckon this amount of switching is a real bottleneck? a real problem is the 1.5 factor of copying the arrays each time, which I'd be happy to get rid of, but I guess that's the price for not knowing the maximal size (I might just use your hack with a ridiculous initial size, as long as it fits in the RAM).

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be the bottleneck without actually profiling the code (cProfile and line_profiler are really helpful as will as timeit). It's really going to depend on your particular application.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically increase the size of an existing array (and therefore do it in-place), `numpy.ndarray.resize` must be used instead of `numpy.resize`. This method is NOT implemented in Python, and is not available in Numba, so it just cannot be done.